# ASP: button to input submit

Tags: asp.net, button, form-submit, clientid

I am trying to use literalcontrol to add a button as input type="submit"

```
litLevelList.Text += string.Format(" &lt input type='submit' id='{0}' value='{1}' name='{2}' >", btnSave.ClientID, Lang.Trans("Save Changes " )  , btnSave. ??);
```

I could get the button ID using CLientID but without the name the data doesnt seems to be submitted.

Could anyone tell me how i could access the name value rendered by ASP for a button control.

thanks,
vishnu

Comment: whats wrong with a asp:Button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really must build the control, try using a HtmlGenericControl or a PlaceHolder control

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.htmlcontrols.htmlgenericcontrol.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.placeholder.aspx

**UPDATE**

This works for me:

```
    LiteralControl txtText = new LiteralControl();
    txtText.Text = "Something";
txtText.Text += "<input type='submit' text='Okay' id='" + btnSave.ClientID + "' name='" + btnSave.UniqueID + "'>"; 
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txtText);
```

Comment: The requirement is pretty weird. I need to place a button in a literal control. Since i cant added a button to a  literal control i had to manually type the rendered content of a button (if it makes sense).